# Why would "null" work, but not null?

Tags: javascript, null

I have been writing some code pertaining to random number generating, and I would add the user's name to the sentence that was produced by the script.

The user inputs their answer with a prompt. I wanted to know how to check for `null`, so I tested this with the answer given by multiple sources on Stack Overflow. However, it does not work for `null`. Curiously, it does work when `null` is inputted as a string: `"null"`. I have read over and over again that `null` is not a string, so why would that work?
My code for the test is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Check</title>
    <script>
      var name = prompt("What's up?");
      function check() {
        if (name === null) {
          document.write("null");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body id="body" onload="check()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see the problem now ... change `name` to something else, because `name` is a window property that will mess you up!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is purely the choice of variable name ... i.e. `name`

the code with (almost) any other variable name will work "as expected"

`var name = ...` in the global scope is essentially the same as `window.name = ...`

Now, `window.name` is defined as the name of the window ... this is usually an empty string. if you window.open a window, giving a name, the `window.name` will be that value in the new window

Now, assigning `null` to `window.name` will actually result in `window.name == 'null'` because window.name can not be a non string type. In fact assigning any non-string value to `window.name` will result in `window.name` having the ".toString()" value

try

```
window.name = true; // window.name will be the string "true";
window.name = {key: "value"}; // window.name will be the string "[object Object]";
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

When someone types the input, it is received by the script as a String.  So if someone types *null* it translates to "null", i.e. a String with value *null*.  So when you try to evaluate it to the value null it does not work.  However if you evaluate it to the String "null" it will match.

EDIT: If you do not want to allow user to enter null or any other malicious values, create a list of such strings and check against them. Treat them as string values

The function does execute when you hit Cancel aswell, but since you are cancelling the operation, the value of name is set as "null". That is how the prompt function works.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: To add to poushy's answer, you need to check if the string is empty rather than `null` - https://jsfiddle.net/orrLqtfm/.

Comment: you should still check for `null` to test if the `cancel` button was pressed

Comment: If you do not want to allow user to enter null or any other malicious values, create a list of such strings and check against them.  Treat them as string values.

Comment: @JaromandaX I think you misinterpreted my original question. I **am** testing for the cancel button. I am sorry if I did not make that clear. When I run the code I posted above, and hit the cancel button, the function does not execute.

Comment: @MCBlastoise I wasn't referring to your question, which is why the comment is in this answer

Comment: @JaromandaX Oh sorry. I'm kinda new to this.

Comment: And to @MaxSindwani, it does work when I test for an empty string. It just doesn't work for the cancel button.

Comment: No probs, see comment to your question ... you've picked a variable name that will be problematic ... a quirk of the browser ... `name` is always a string because `name` is a predefined property of `window` that has will mess you up, like you've seen

Comment: @MCBlastoise Ah, then yeah you'll need to check for null specifically if you want to differentiate between submit and cancel - https://jsfiddle.net/msindwan/orrLqtfm/3/

Comment: in this case, `name` will never be `null`, `Name` would, so would `nAme` but not `name` - quirk of the global (window) object

Comment: Thanks so much, @JaromandaX! This was the reason it kept failing. I'm new to Javascript, and so I didn't know about name being a special keyword.

Comment: @JaromandaX - The function does execute when you hit Cancel aswell, but since you are cancelling the operation, the value of name is set as "null".  That is how the prompt function works.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Comment: @poushy - the `check` function **in the question** will execute regardless ... the issue is with the choice of variable name as I've stated

Comment: Yes you are right @JaromandaX - the naming messes with the fact that it delegates to a string.